# "sprintf" raising exception using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c, visual-studio, printf

I tried to compile this program using:

- Visual Studio 2013
- Watcom

On Watcom it compiles and runs perfectly.

On Visual Studio the second `sprintf` raises an exception.

**Program:**

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
//-------------------------------------------------------//
    char        *filename = 0;
    filename = (char *)malloc(100* sizeof(char));   // allocate

    sprintf(filename, "Test");                      // write to string ok

    filename = "Test";                              // write to string

    sprintf(filename, "Test");                      // write to string fails VisualStudio2013.

    getchar();
}
```

I don't understand what happens. Can anybody explain?

Comment: Can you actually add the exception here?

Comment: `filename = "Test";` you cannot write to static allocated storage after with `sprintf(filename, "Test");`.

Comment: *On Watcom it compiles and runs perfectly.*  It does not run "perfectly", unless "perfectly" means your program didn't crash.  You are creating a memory leak by overwriting the pointer that was returned by `malloc`.

Comment: Also, many old (and I will include Watcom here) Windows/DOS based C / C++ compilers allowed string literals to be (erroneously) modified.   That's a reason why many programs that were written using these old compilers when ported to another OS or to a modern C++ compiler, would crash.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I understand what went wrong. The "real" program was developed on watcom and worked for years without crash. Even the pointer could be deallocated.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:**

```
filename = "Test";
```

does not write the contents of `"Test"` into `filename`. It makes it point to the string literal `"Test"` instead.

---

**Explanation:**

```
char        *filename = 0;
```

`filename` points to `NULL`.

```
filename = (char *)malloc(100* sizeof(char));
```

`filename` now points to the start of the allocated memory segment (assuming `malloc` succeeds in allocating memory).

```
sprintf(filename, "Test");
```

5 slots starting with the one `filename` is currently pointing to is filled with characters of `"Test"`. In other words, `"Test"` is written to `filename`.

```
filename = "Test";
```

The location where `filename` points to is changed and now, it points to the string literal `"Test"` (Specifically, it points to the address of the first character of the string literal `"Test"`). Thus, you lose track of the allocated memory leading to a memory leak as you don't (and can't as you've lost track of the allocated memory) free the allocated memory after its use.

```
sprintf(filename, "Test");
```

The above `sprintf` writes `"Test"` into the location `filename` points to.

But, string literals are immutable, meaning that they cannot be changed. Attempting to change the contents of a string literal results in undefined behavior. So, writing into the location changes the contents of the string literal `filename` points to resuling in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = "Test"; // Make filename point to a constant

sprintf(filename, "Test");    // try to modify what filename points to
```

You can't modify a constant, that's what makes them constant.